# Error with relationships between entities and setter function

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm from yesterday fighting with this problem,  and I don`t find any solution.

I have two entities interrelated as follows:

```
// src/FEB/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace FEB\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="feb_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // tu propia lógica
}
}
```

Account.php

```
namespace FEB\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Account
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FEB\UserBundle\Entity\AccountRepository")
*/
class Account
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
    *
    * @var ArrayCollection $idusr
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\FEB\UserBundle\Entity\User")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="accounts_users",
    *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="usr_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    * )
    */
    private $idusr;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->idusr = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

/**
 * Set idusr
 *
 * @param string $idusr
 * @return Account
 */
public function setIdusr($idusr)
{
    $this->idusr = $idusr;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idusr
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdusr()
{
    return $this->idusr;
}
```

There is no form to be built, since the user does not have to enter any data, only use the setter for this, not the buildForm method in AccountType.
In Account entity , all the setter function work fine except setter of the field related to the User entity, "setIdusr". It throws me this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\FEB\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 528 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\FEB\vendor\doctrine\collections\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php line 47
```

How I can fix this?

Thank you in advanced.

Edit: I will try to explain how it should be functioning: When I create a new account, it should automatically create an entry in the relationship table "account_user" with the id of the new account id and user id.

Comment: The 2 provided classes / files are not the files mentioned in the error! can you provide the lines of error please?  
UnitOfWork.php on line 528   
ArrayCollection.php line 47

Comment: The error is very clear. you're passing an string to some class __construct($variable) where an array is expected.

Comment: That classes: UnitOfWork.php on line 528 ArrayCollection.php line 47 are core class of Symfony2. I don't write that classes. I built these entity relationships in other cases and it worked perfectly, the only difference is that they built the form so that the user entered data and now It's the application which entered the data, no forms.

Comment: I will try to explain how it should be functioning: When I create a new account, it should automatically create an entry in the relationship table "account_user" with the id of the new account id and user id.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see now, in the parent class you're $id is private and than in the child class you're defining it again as protected.

so either don't use the same variable name.
or define it in the parent as protected.

Comment: Same error, I've defined $id protected and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved!!!, 
I had to create a "addUser" method in Account entity and then I had to pass a User object parameter. 
I was passing a string as parameter and that was the error.